# Gradle is not listing task for custom build variant in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Running command - `./gradlew tasks` does not list custom build variant task & yarn android is complaining for

```
Task 'installPaceondemanddevdebug' not found in project ':app'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallPaceondemanddevdebug'.
```

Can someone please help understanding how to regenerate by any gradle command.